# Check if two date ranges overlap in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Events have `start_at` and `end_at` fields

How do I check if there is any overlap between two events using only database queries?

In other words, is something like

```
(Event1.start_at BETWEEN Event2.start_at AND Event2.end_at) OR (Event1.end_at BETWEEN Event2.start_at AND Event2.end_at)
```

possible with .where function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, it also has a [BETWEEN ... AND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) (which is just a shortcut for (min <= expr AND expr <= max)).